# Not able to insert a string to a position in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to iterate over two data frames with different lenghts in order to look for some data in a string. If the data is found, I should be able to add info to a specific position in a data frame. Here is the code.

In the `df` data frame, I created an empty column, which is going to receive the data in the future.

I also have the `df_userstory` data frame. And here is where I'm looking for the data. So, I created the code below.

Both `df['Issue key'][i]` and `df_userstory['parent_of'][i]` contains strings.

```
df['parent'] = ""

for i in df_userstory.index:
    if df['Issue key'][i] in df_userstory['parent_of'][i]:
        item = df_userstory['Issue key'][i]
        df['parent'].iloc[i] = item

df
```

For some reason, when I run this code the `df['parent']` remains empty. I've tried different approaches, but everything failed.

I've tried to do the following in order to check what was happening:

```
df['parent'] = ""

for i in df_userstory.index:
    if df['Issue key'][i] in df_userstory['parent_of'][i]:
        print('True')
```

Nothing was printed out.

I appreciate your help here.

Cheers

Comment: You probably should be using `merge`.

Comment: Why? I don't want to merge the data frames. I just need to add a string to a specific field. I think `merge` is used to merge data frames. Am I wrong?

Comment: What happens if you print : `df['Issue key'][i]` and `df_userstory['parent_of'][i]` before the `if`?

Comment: It returns the strings. 

`df['Issue key'][i]` returns -> XXXXXXXXXXXXX-123
`df_userstory['parent_of'][i]` returns -> XXXXXXXXXXXXX-123, XXXXXXXXXXXXX-464, XXXXXXXXXXXXX-465, XXXXXXXXXXXXX-466

Comment: Hmm, I don't think you can use `in` like that if they are strings. You should try str.find instead? `if df['parent_of'][i].find(df_userstory['Issue key'][i]) != -1:`

Comment: Same thing. Nothing was printed. It's so weird.

Answer (score 0):

Iterating over each index will lose all the performance benefits of using Pandas dataframe.
You should use dataframe `merge`.

```
# select the two columns you need from df_userstory
df_us = df_userstory.loc[:, ['parent_of', 'Issue key']]

# rename to parent, that will be merged with df dataframe
df_us.rename(columns={'Issue key': 'parent'}, inplace=True).drop_duplicates()

# merge
df = df.merge(df_us, left_on='Issue key', right_on='parent_of', how='left')
```

Ref: [Pandas merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

Comment: I cannot just merge, because I need to check if the string I have in `df['Issue key'][i]` is in `df_userstory['parent_of'][i]` which always returns something like -> XXXXXXXXXXXXX-123, XXXXXXXXXXXXX-464, XXXXXXXXXXXXX-465, XXXXXXXXXXXXX-466